# Evitar mostrar algunos archivos y a la vez ciertos parámetros en la url con htacess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

Estoy intentando arreglar o cambiar algunas rutas que aparecen en la url preparadas con .htaccess que o no deberían salir completas o incluso evitar que si el usuario pone algunas de estas se muestre cierto contenido.

Lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera:

Index.php

```
<?php

/*=============================================
CONTENIDO DINÁMICO
=============================================*/

$rutas = array();
$ruta = null;

if(isset($_GET["ruta"])){   

    $rutas = explode("/", $_GET["ruta"]);       

    /*=============================================
    LISTA BLANCA DE URL'S AMIGABLES
    =============================================*/

    if($rutas[0] == "inicio" || $rutas[0] == "contacto"){
        
        include $rutas[0].".php";                       

    }else{      

        header('Location: inicio');         

    }

}else{

    include "inicio.php";

}

?>
```

htaccess

```
# Impedir que se pueda ver el listado de contenidos de un directorio
Options All -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9ñÑ_/]+)$ index.php?ruta=$1


RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://midominio.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirigir la URL con www a la dirección sin www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.midominio.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://midominio.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Hasta aquí lo que logro es que cuando el usuario ponga en la url o el dominio completo o una de las dos palabras de la lista blanca como "inicio" o "contacto" cargue correctamente el contenido, por ejemplo así:

https://midominio.com/

https://midominio.com/inicio

https://midominio.com/contacto

Y si por ejemplo una persona escribe otra palabra que no sea una de las de la lista blanca redirige a inicio, ejemplo:

https://midominio.com/algo -> https://midominio.com/

Hasta aquí todo bien, sin embargo veo varios errores que no deberían ocurrir o al menos no se como evitar por ahora, por ejemplo:

1- Si el usuario añade una barra final "/" y escribe https://midominio.com/inicio/ el dominio carga sin su hoja de estilos, por lo tanto aquí ¿debo de aplicar una redirección a la ruta sin "/"?

2- Si el usuario escribe o añade un carácter no permitido como "." por ejemplo https://midominio.com/inicio. me muestra un directorio de opciones y documentos disponibles

> Multiple Choices. The document name you requested (/inicio.) could not
> be found on this server. However, we found documents with names
> similar to the one you requested.  Available documents: /inicio.php
> (common basename)

¿Aquí debo de evitarlo también con una redirección 301?

3- Si el usuario intenta ver un directorio, por ejemplo el de imágenes https://midominio.com/imagenes en vez de evitarlo y redirigir a inicio me da un error de redirección

> Esta página no funciona La página midominio.com te ha redirigido
> demasiadas veces. Borrar las cookies. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

4- Si el usuario escribe https://midominio.com/contacto?ruta=contacto o
https://midominio.com/index.php?ruta=inicio/ me cargan correctamente sin embargo me gustaría que en la url solo se pueda ver como mucho https://midominio.com/inicio o https://midominio.com/contacto

5- Si el usuario escribe https://midominio.com/index.php carga perfectamente sin embargo me gustaría ver como hacer que no aparezca la extensión "php" y tampoco la palabra index. Aquí he probado varias opciones con RewriteCond y RewriteRule pero tampoco me funcionan.

En general ¿qué podría añadir o eliminar de lo actual?

**EDICIÓN**
El nuevo index.php cambiado.

El nuevo archivo htaccess queda así por ahora

```
# -- Impedir que se pueda ver el listado de contenidos de un directorio
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# --Eliminar extensión .php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ https://midominio.com/ [R=301,L]
# Abajo el resto de reglas

# -- Redirigir la URL a https
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://midominio.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# -- Redirigir la URL con www a la dirección sin www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.midominio.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://midominio.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# --No existe archivo !-f, no existe directorio !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

ErrorDocument 404 /error404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error403.php

RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9ñÑ_/.]+)$ index.php?ruta=$1
```

**Arreglados**

1 - El tema de la barra "/" final en la url y que no se vean ciertas hojas de estilos, imágenes, etc etc lo he cambiado añadiendo la ruta absoluta   y luego aplicando a cada img, css y arreglado. css/style.css">

2- Si el usuario escribe o añade un carácter no permitido como "." por ejemplo https://midominio.com/inicio. me muestra un directorio de opciones y documentos disponibles (añadido el caracter "." y así no da ese error -> RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9ñÑ_/.]+)$ index.php?ruta=$1)

3- Si el usuario intenta ver un directorio, por ejemplo el de imágenes https://midominio.com/img en vez de evitarlo y redirigir a inicio me da un error de redirección
Ahora me da error 403 y muestro el nuevo archivo 403.php

**Pendientes**

4- Si el usuario escribe https://midominio.com/index.php?ruta=inicio/ me carga correctamente hacia la ruta principal sin embargo  https://midominio.com/contacto?ruta=contacto se mantiene en la url

¿Se puede evitar con el htacess actual o aun queda pendiente desde el index.php?

5- Si el usuario escribe https://midominio.com/index.php carga perfectamente hacia la ruta principal sin php, pero si cargo contacto.php o incluso añado más enlaces como galería.php, quienes-somos.php etc etc

¿debo de añadir en htacess una nueva redirección por acada archivo.php a redirigir o se puede hacer desde php con un array siempre dentro de las rutas blancas que yo le añada?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No listar contenido de directorios, cambia tu regla quitando `All`:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Para evitar que se abra `index.php` no incluyas parámetros adicionales (`$1`), simplemente lleva a la raíz del sitio:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ https://midominio.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Redirigir cualquier '/ruta.php' a '/ruta', quitando la extensión

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ https://midominio.com/$1 [L,R=301]
# Abajo el resto de reglas
```

Tu regla para usar solo las rutas que deseas debe ir hasta el final y solo si se trata de un archivo o directorio que no existe, de lo contrario, incluso imágenes, CSS, JS y directorios que necesitas serán redirigidos y, por supuesto, obtendrás el error `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`:

```
# No existe archivo !-f, no existe directorio !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9ñÑ_/]+)$ index.php?ruta=$1
```

Te recomiendo usar un array para verificar las rutas:

> ruta => [nombre-de-ruta-para-menú-o-título, archivo-a-incluir]

```
$rutas = [
    'inicio' => ['Inicio', 'inicio.php'],
    'contacto' => ['Contacto', 'contacto.php']
];
// Obtener ruta desde $_GET o inicializar como cadena vacía:
$ruta = (isset($_GET['ruta'])) ? $_GET['ruta'] : '';

// Forzar que 'inicio' no aparezca como parámetro en URL
if($ruta == 'inicio') {
    // Redirige a raíz del sitio
    header('Location: https://midominio.com/');
}

// Hay diagonales?
$params = explode('/', $ruta);
$abrir = ($params[0] == '') ? 'inicio' : $params[0];
// Verificar que la ruta existe
if(isset($rutas[$abrir])) {
    // Si hay más de 1 parámetro, es porque hay diagonal al final
    if(count($params) > 1) {
        // Redirigir sin diagonal
        header("Location: https://midominio.com/$abrir");
    }
    // Incluir archivo de ruta
    include $rutas[$abrir][1];
    // Finalizar script
    exit;
}
// Aquí deberías mostrar una página con error 404: No encontrada
```

### Resumen de tus problemas:

1. Diagonal al final: Deberías usar rutas absolutas para enlazar recursos (css, js, imágenes, etc.). De todos modos, en PHP ya está la opción para redirigir si está presente.
2. El usuario agrega `/.` y se lista el contenido del directorio: Se debería solucionar con el primer código de esta respuesta.
3. Usuario quiere ver un directorio: Ya no se va a redirigir y tampoco se mostrará el contenido del directorio.
4. y 5. Debe redirigir de `index.php` a la raíz del dominio.

Todavía quedan validaciones por hacer, como verificar si existen más parámetros de los que necesitas o caracteres *no esperados* en la URL: `?`, `&`, pero ya tienes un buen punto de partida.

Por cierto, el arreglo `$rutas` también te servirá para generar menús, por ejemplo:

```
function menu() {
    global $rutas, $abrir;
    foreach($rutas as $ruta => $valores) {
        // Es la página que actualmente se está mostrando?
        $actual = ($ruta == $abrir) ? ' class="menu-actual"' : '';
        echo "<a href=\"/$ruta\"$actual>{$valores[1]}</a>\n";
    }
}
```

**Edición:**

Arriba agregué la opción para evitar que entren directamente en contacto.php o quienes-somos.php y lleve a /contacto o /quienes-somos.

En cuanto al signo de interrogación `?`, no sé que tan conveniente sea evitarlo, porque no podrás hacer peticiones GET, pero puedes intentar con esto (antes de las reglas .php):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^?]*)\?
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]
```

No lo he probado, así que te tocará comentarnos como va.

Comment: He añadido los cambios como edición en el mensaje anterior, tanto el nuevo index.php como en el htaccess sin embargo algunos puntos aun quedan pendientes como el 4 y 5 que sería ampliar el cambio de index.php y la ruta entera que funciona bien en los puntos 4 y 5 pero en otros futuros archivos como, quienes-somos.php, galeria.php o el actual contacto.php aun me faltaría prepararlo. ¿Sería con un array en el index o añadir cada nuevo archivo en htaccess o un htaccess que recoga cualquier nombre en la url que elimine directamente esa extenión .php o más parámetros?. Muchas gracias @Triby

Comment: Revisa ahora, en la parte de arriba agregué código para evitar acceso a _archivo.php_ y, hasta abajo, para _query string_

Comment: Pues parece que en principio funciona todo perfectamente incluyendo el no ver las extensiones .php en la url como que en la url no aparece por completo ?ruta=archivo.  
Muchas gracias por tu gran ayuda @Triby PD ¿Eres el mismo Triby que conozco hace años ya de FW? Saludos.

Comment: Excelente, me alegra que ya funcione. Sí el mismo Triby. Saludos.